# .net 5.0 change default value of a content-security-policy header

Tags: .net, header, response, content-security-policy

I'm implementing a simple web application on .net 5.0. 
On the page I have the following element:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0..." >
```

When I'm running a code on my local machine, everything goes well. But when I run it on the server, I've noticed, that the image is not displayed. 
The reason is

> Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...' because
> it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "default-src https:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
> 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I've already tried the following solutions:

1. Add the following meta-tag in the markup:

2. Add the web.config file with the following content:

```
   <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear/>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

3. Added a custom header direct in the controller and in the middleware.

The result of all these actions is: I have now 2 csp response headers:

> content-security-policy: default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; 
> content-security-policy: default-src https:

The second one is standard, the first one is my.

If anybody knows if it's possible and how to change the default value of a CSP response header, please share your ideas. Because in the current situation I don't see any possibility of using IMG element with inline data inside.

Comment: The only workaround I found is to save an image and insert it's URL to the src attribute of a img element. But it seems it's really only a workaround and not a solving of an initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

The header

> content-security-policy: default-src https:

was added not by the .net, but by the proxy.
As a result: the problem is not valid and should be solved by a network configuration.